# Using jQuery, Clear the rest of the Options/DIVs after choosing from dropdown-list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the js i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#box1').hide();
           $('#box2').hide();
           $('#box3').hide();
           $("#thechoices").change(function(){
              if(this.value == 'all'){
                     $("#boxes").children().show();
                  }else{
                     $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
                  }
           });          
           $("#thechoices").change(); 
        });
</script>
```

---

And the Html:

```
    <div id="boxes">
       <div id="box1"><p>Box 1 stuff…</p></div>
       <div id="box2"><p>Box 2 stuff…</p></div>
       <div id="box3"><p>Box 3 stuff…</p></div>
    </div>
```

I need to clear (empty) all the rest of the options/divs after choosing from the dropdown-list, (even if i opened the source code they won't appear) and disable the dropdown-list in the same time,

how to achieve that?

Comment: create boxes dynamically.

Comment: Can you include the html for your `#thechoices` select

Comment: `_(even if i opened the source code they won't appear)_` only works if elems created dynamically in jQuery.

Comment: <select id="thechoices">
<option value="box1">Box 1</option>
<option value="box2">Box 2</option>
<option value="box3">Box 3</option>
<option value="all">All Boxes</option>
</select>

Comment: @haim770, could you plz write the entire script?

Comment: Ok, appears to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ubADX/ What are you doing differently?

Comment: @Jamiec, You wrote the same structure i have!!!

Comment: @haim770, what's the point, the result just like i don't have dropdown anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Remove hidden elements:

```
$('#boxes').remove('div:hidden');
```

Disable drop-down:

```
$('#thechoices').attr('disabled', true);
```

Hence:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#boxes > div').hide();

       $("#thechoices").change(function(){
          if(this.value == 'all')
              $("#boxes").children().show();
          else
              $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();

          $('#boxes').remove('div:hidden'); // remove hidden boxes from DOM
          $(this).attr('disabled', true); // disable drop down
       });

       $("#thechoices").change(); 
    });
```

Comment: they'll still show in "view source" because they are part of the source

Comment: "View Source" will usually just show the html received *from the server*. if you want to see the current DOM as structured (and manipulated by JavaScript) in browser memory you can use FireBug inspector and the like.

Comment: my point exactly. PO specifically requires that they are not shown in "view source" `even if i opened the source code they won't appear`

Comment: Since he used `jQuery` to manipulates the DOM it's obvious he wants to  remove elements in the client side and not on the server side (which not mentioned at all).

"Source code" for that matter just meant DOM structure (as i get it).

Comment: source code is something static and the DOM is something dynamic. That said you might be right that OP is using the term incorrectly though and what he really is asking for is to remove it from the dom and not the source code

Answer (score 0):

Like Jai said maybe what you are looking for is create them dynamically.

what you are looking for is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box1').hide();
    $('#box2').hide();
    $('#box3').hide();
    $("#thechoices").change(function(){
        if(this.value == 'all'){
            $("#boxes").children().show();
        }else{
            $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().remove();
            $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });          
    $("#thechoices").change(); 
});
```

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/rJtLk/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements right then change the script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#thechoices").change(function(){
              var self = $(this);
              if(self.val() !== 'all'){
                     self.attr('disabled',true);
                     $("#boxes").empty();
              }
           });          
           $("#boxes").append('<div id="box1"><p>Box 1 stuff…</p></div>       <div id="box2">p>Box 2 stuff…</p></div>       <div id="box3"><p>Box 3 stuff…</p></div>');
});
</script>
```

and the HTMl snippet to (no nested divs)

```
<div id="boxes">
</div>
```

If you add the boxes dynamically they will not show in view source (view source shows the html as it was send from the server). and then when you change the value of the selection you simply disable the selection and empty the `boxes` div